# Constraints for MySQL TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, timestamp, constraints

Is it possible to have a timestamp constraint in mysql that MUST come from the system and can not otherwise be provided in the insert or update query?

Is it possible to keep a table from being updated with a constraint? I understand how to keep a mysql user from updating a table with GRANT but in my case a constraint may be preferred as it is my goal to guarantee the timestamp of the record regardless of user including root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to overwrite the value on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)

So no matter what the query sets, the value of your desired timestamp field will always be the system time.

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER before_yourtable_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.datefield := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END;;

CREATE TRIGGER before_yourtable_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.datefield := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT 1:**
Just realized you actually wanted to prevent that the once set system time could be updated later.
Slightly modify your UPDATE trigger to have this job done.

`SET NEW.datefield := OLD.datefield` resets the value to the old value on each update

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_yourtable_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.datefield := OLD.datefield;
END;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
MYSQL has a constraint to have a single field in table having a default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
For the insert queries this will work

```
Create table foo
(

logged_date  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

But for updation, you need to handle it in a different way either through `triggers` or in your application code